# Easy writeline for debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging

Does there exist some easy to use solution to just do a writeline for debugging in the output window in Visual Studio. I know about `Trace.WriteLine` and `Debug.WriteLine`, but they seems to only work in debug mode, and actually both om them sometimes comes with some hardship.

I just want to writeline!! always:) Actually it would be fine to also be able to see those writelines in production.

Any tips much appreciated

Comment: There is `Console.WriteLine` which does exactly what it's claims to do - writes to standard output.

Comment: Ah, you seem to use classic ASP.NET, where that will not have an effect. So for debugging just use `Debug.WriteLine` or better the [VS debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022) itself which is quite powerful allowing to do a lot of things (including conditional breakpoints). For everything else - use logging.

Comment: You tried writing to file? Have a custom class with a method to write to any file to any location you like. Just call your method whenever you need.

Can you add some more details about the application? is a console or web?

Comment: You can try to use [Trace Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.trace?view=net-7.0) and [TextWriterTraceListener Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's take the debug.print (or debug.Writeline).

So, the first thing is to setup Visual Studio to send that output to the Immediate window.

Thus tools->options->Debugging.

You want to select this option:

[image]

So, now, if you building desktop, or asp.net applications, then you have one common output window.

And you can add this to your asp.net project:

```
    public static void MyLog(string sText)
    {
        string sJava = "";
        sJava = $@"<script>console.log('{sText}')</script>;";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(sJava)

    }
```

So, say we drop a button onto a web page, F5 to run, and now we have this:

[image]

So, by default, Visual Studio does not provide a console.

So, with this code behind button stub:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.Print("This is my button click");

        string MyZoo = "Hello";
        General.MyLog("Value of MyZoo = " + MyZoo);
    }
```

However, note the above 2nd code, called MyLog. That sends the "log" to the browser side debug tools. So, if I hit F12 (browser tools), then I see this:

[image]

So, you can send "console.log" commands to the browser side, and thus both client side, and server side can display info in the one browser side console.

> Actually it would be fine to also be able to see those WriteLine’s in production.

No, you don't want to do that, since there is a RATHER HIGH cost in performance.  If you need some type of logging system, then adopt some kind of system that writes information out to a log file or some such.

Comment: Thanks! I think we will use our own web-based log system :)